# JQL issues added to backlog

Tags: jira, agile, jql

Is there a way in JQL to find issues that were added to backlog yesterday? I tried using Sprint changed to EMPTY and Backlog priority changed from empty but JIRA doesn't support historical search on those fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQL indeed does not support history searches on the sprint field so you cannot search for issues that were removed from a sprint since yesterday.

You can however search for "new" issues that were added to the backlog since yesterday:

```
project = "MyProject" AND created > -1d AND sprint IS EMPTY
```

Or for issues on your backlog that were updated since yesterday:

```
project = "MyProject" AND updated > -1d AND sprint IS EMPTY
```

If that's not close enough to what you need, you could also use an add-on like [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) which comes with a number of JQL functions built-in, like [removedAfterSprintStart](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_removedaftersprintstart). It also allows you to [implement your own JQL functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/custom-jql-functions.html). That way you could implement exactly the behavior that you desire.